# How can I get a user's ACF data when using a template part in a WP_User_Query?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a template part to repeat the HTML for each result when performing a `WP_User_Query` to return a list of users. However I am finding that the Advanced Custom Fields data isn't returning.

```
// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'role'      => 'advisor',
    'number'    => 6
);
// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) :
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
        get_template_part('template-parts/advisor');
    }
endif;
```

...and a simple example of the template part itself:

```
<?php
    $advisor_heading = get_field('advisor_heading', 'user_'.$user->ID);
?>

<div class="advisor__heading">
    <h2><?php echo $advisor_heading; ?></h2>
</div>
```

So the HTML is returning of course, but the ACF user data is not. It works fine if I don't use a template part and instead hard code it into the foreach loop, but in this case I need to use the template part.

Hope somebody can help!

Answer (score 0):

[It is possible to pass arguments through the get_template_part() function.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) Try passing your user variable through the `get_template_part()` function.

```
get_template_part('template-parts/advisor', null, ['user' => $user]);
```

Then in your template you can retrieve it instead from the args array.

```
$advisor_heading = get_field('advisor_heading', 'user_'.$args['user']->ID);
```